# Add new attribute to IPA user info (Linux)

Tags: linux, rhel, users, ldap, freeipa

I am not sure its so straightforward on the Linux side.
I want to add a new attribute to identify users as Contractor or Government.
Is this recommended or possible within LDAP?

Comment: It is certainly possible to modify the LDAP schema to add an attribute, assuming that a suitable attribute in a class does not already exist. For example, [`inetOrgPerson` already has "employee type"](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2798#page-4) which might be suitable. However, you could also model the domain differently (using a different/additional OU for example), or perhaps just using groups. I think providing a few scenarios about how you want to filter/search, etc. would help.

Comment: Thank you. For example: ipa user-show jdoe -all  would show a field of Status: Contractor or Status: Government.